# AlpineJS: @click doesn't work on <option> tag

Tags: javascript, onclick, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I'd like to make changes value using `@click` in `<option>`, how can improve it while the code seems like `@click` inside on `<option>`

```
 <x-input select class=" w-[270px] h-10 duration-100" x-bind:disabled="modal ? true : false">
     @foreach (DB::table('t930_calendar_name')->get() as $v)
         <option value="{{ $v->c_calendar_name }}" 
                 @click="confirm ? modal = true : subActive = '{{ $v->c_calendar_name }}'; tempSubActive =  '{{ $v->c_calendar_name }}'">
             {{ $v->c_calendar_name }}
         </option>
     @endforeach
 </x-input>
```

I have tried but the value doesn't change, I've try like this to check the value changed.

```
<span x-text="subActive + ' subActive'"></span><br>
<span x-text="tempSubActive + ' tempSubActive'"></span><br>
```

Comment: I've just tested a very simple click handler (in Firefox) which has worked fine. What is `confirm` in this context? Are there any console errors?

Comment: @Yinci when the input has been inputted confirm change to true, it's just make sure the input has been changed. confirm is served in another component.

the other console there is no error.

Comment: Is there an active `x-data` attribute on any of the parent elements? Without it, Alpine doesn't trigger, and since you don't have errors I assume the code itself is fine.

Comment: yes there is, I think <option> is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved. Using this one

```
<x-input select class="w-[270px] h-10 duration-100" 
         @change="confirm ? modal = true : subActive = $event.target.value; 
         confirm ? tempSubActive = $event.target.value : tempSubActive = subActive; 
         confirm ? $event.target.value = subActive : tempSubActive = subActive;"
         x-bind:disabled="modal ? true : false">
         @foreach (DB::table('t930_calendar_name')->get() as $v)
                <option value="{{ $v->c_calendar_name }}"
                     x-text="tempSubActive != subActive ? tempSubActive : '{{ $v->c_calendar_name }}'">
                </option>
         @endforeach
</x-input>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).